# How to use arara

Tags: winedt, arara

Hello after compiling the code found below using WinEdt 10 PDFLaTeX, I ran arara from the accessories menu but got an error `I didn't get any directives in 'animated1.tex' , so didn't do anything...`

Can you tell me how to use arara for this code:

```
%arara: animate: {density: 160, delay: 8}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\foreach \mainangle [count=\xx, evaluate=\mainangle as \mark using (\mainangle/45)] in {0,5,...,355,360}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    set layers,
    x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,
    xmin=-3.7, xmax=8.2,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top,
    xtick={2,4,6,8},
    ytick={-1,-.5,.5,1},
    xticklabels={$90^{\circ} (\pi/2)$, $180^{\circ} (\pi)$, $270^{\circ} (3\pi/2)$,$360^{\circ} (2\pi)$},
    xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    yticklabels={-1,-0.5,0.5,1},
    ylabel={$\sin(x)$}, y label style={anchor=west},
    xlabel={$x$}, x label style={anchor=south},
]
\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\addplot [fill=white] coordinates {(-4,-2) (8.5,-2) (8.5,2) (-4,2)} \closedcycle;
\endpgfonlayer

\path[name path=xaxis] (axis cs:-4,0) -- (axis cs:8,0);
\coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);

% plot and circle
\addplot [samples=100,domain=0:8, name path=myplot](\x,{3 * sin(\x*45)/pi});
\draw[name path=circle] (axis cs:-2.5,0) circle (1.5cm);

% fill in circle and plot
\draw[black,fill=blue!40] (axis cs:-2.5,0) -- (axis cs:-1.5,0) arc (0:\mainangle:1.5cm) coordinate (cc) -- cycle;
\path[name path=mark] (axis cs:\mark,-1) -- (axis cs:\mark,1);
% small circles
\draw (cc) circle (3pt);

\path[name intersections={of=mark and myplot,by=cp}];
\draw (cp) circle (3pt);
\draw (cc) -- (cp) -- (cp|-O);

\ifnum\mainangle<5
\else
\addplot[blue!30] fill between[of=xaxis and myplot, soft clip={domain=-1:\mark}];
\fi
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226407/1160) help?

Comment: You wrote `%arara:` but arara needs a space: `% arara:`

Comment: Looks like arara is being called, but you haven't specified your directive correctly

Comment: @cmhughes Can you tell me how to specify the directive?  Thanks!

Comment: See Arzigoglu's comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a space in the arara directive.

The right one should be:

```
% arara: animate: {density: 160, delay: 8}
```

Remember that this directive works if you have the `animate.yaml` rule as in [this cmhughes's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117972/80972) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed (during install time remember to check the option "Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)" otherwise `convert.exe` won't be installed).

Also you need to have compiled the source file into `.pdf` otherwise the conversion cannot start.

So I suggest you to add the rule

```
% arara: pdflatex
```

before the above one and let arara do the whole work for you.

**EDIT**

Supposing that you're going to place your `animate.yaml` in the folder `C:\arara\myrules`, the contents of `araraconfig.yaml` must be

```yaml
!config
paths:
- C:\arara\myrules
```

The file `araraconfig.yaml` has to be placed in the folder `C:\Users\<Username>`, where `<Username>` is your Windows User Account name.

Comment: I got ImageMagick installed correctly, but still not sure how and where to put the animate.yaml file?  What do I have to do to get this to work with WinEdt?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe You first have to create an `araraconfig.yaml` file in `C:\Users\Username` with your custom paths as described in the preface of section 6 ("Configuration file") and subsection 6.1 ("Search paths") of the [arara manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf). Then put your `animate.yaml` in one of the paths listed there.

Comment: @Joe Have you been able to make things work properly?

Comment: Not yet...still having issues. I will let you later today if I got anything going.  Thanks for checking in!

Comment: I created the `araraconfig.yaml`, placed it in `C:\Users\Username`. I then created the `animate.yaml` file and placed it in `C:\Program Files\arara\rules\.`  I ran the code above and still got the same error.  I followed the steps that you requested.  DId I place the `animate.yaml` in the wrong place?  Is there something else that needs to be done?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Does the edit in the answer helps?

Comment: I got a little further, but now I get this message: `I'm sorry, but apparently your arara configuration file is
invalid, that is, it has invalid or missing YAML entries.
Unfortunately, arara cannot proceed until the error is fixed. I
tried my best to dump the error message, so here it is:

Problem: Can't construct a java object for
...
Unable to find property 'identifier' on class:
com.github.arara.model.AraraConfiguration
Error found in line 0, column 0.
    !config
    ^`

Comment: @Joe Which version of arara are you using? Note that both MiKTeX and TeX Live come with arara installed.

Comment: I did not know that. I went ahead and downloaded the arara-3.0-installer.exe from `https://bintray.com/cereda/arara/installers/3.0`.  Also, I am using WinEdt.  I installed the package for WinEdt and try to run arara from the Accessories option in WinEdt after running pdfLaTeX

Comment: @Joe Do you have Java installed? arara works only if you have Java on your machine.

Comment: I have Java 8 Update 112 installed on my machine

Comment: @Joe Isn't it that your custom arara installation is interferring with the arara which comes with your TeX distribution? Try uninstalling your custom arara. WinEdt will find the one of the distro.

Comment: this is the beginning of my `animate.yaml` file...`!config
# Arara, the cool TeX automation tool
# Copyright (c) 2012, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda 
# All rights reserved.
#
# This rule is part of arara.
identifier: animate
name: Animate
authors:
- Chris Hughes
- Paulo Cereda
commands:
- name: The Convert program
  command: >...`..., This file is currently placed in the folder where I am  generating the TeX output from WinEdt PDFLaTeX.  Is this file correct?

Comment: This is my `araraconfig.yaml` file...`!config
paths:
- E:\FAU\tests\pgfplots\arara\myrules
identifier: animate
name: animate
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -delay @{delay} -loop @{loop} -density @{density} "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf" "@{ getBasename(file) }.gif"
arguments:
- identifier: delay
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.delay}
  default: 10
- identifier: loop
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.loop}
  default: 0
- identifier: density
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.density}
  default: 300`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59767/discussion-between-joe-and-arzigoglu).