# How to make "xelatex-biber-xelatex-xelatex" in TexWorks?

Tags: texworks

I often need to run **xelatex->biber->xelatex->xelatex** in TexWorks. Is there a way to make TexWorks run them sequentially?

I try to do it with:
[image]

How should I do next?

Comment: Use arara: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226380/how-to-change-typesetting-engine-by-adding-code-to-tex-file/226407#226407

Comment: @Cicada I checked that, but I found it is too difficult to understand. I am using Windows.

Comment: `latexmk` is another method.

Comment: In texworks: name: arara
program: arara
arguments: $fullname

In tex file: % arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

Comment: @Cicada I run *arara* in cmd successfully. But in *texworks*, the error is:　**)\Latex\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar "f:\Important (Could not be deleted)\Latex\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar**　Let me try ***Latexmk***